# How to pull country from JSON data

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am using SwiftyJSON library for JSON parsing. I am not getting the value of the country. I want value of country. I want value "GB".

Following is the JSON:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Country Details",
    "content": 
    {
        "country": "GB"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
let countryJson = response["content"]
let Country = countryJson["country"]
```

Comment: what the result you get here `let countryJson`

Comment: try this `let Country = response["content"]["country"].stringValue`

Comment: How are you using SwiftyJson? countryJson is not swiftyJson's JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
let countryJSON = response["content"] as? [String: String]
let country = countryJSON?["country"]
```